# Which is better, decreasing or increasing ADO.NET SQL Connections?

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading, winforms, ado.net

I have a multi-threaded windows application using more that a background worker. every background worker is using some code to update the same SQL Server database and when it finished it runs again. I have noticed that every background worker is using a single connection. I have created a ConcurrentQueue of a custom class to add all the stored procedures to it and execute it from a single backgorundworker to use just one connection as the database is getting very slow when using many connections.
here is my code
this is the stored procedure class

```
    string _procName;
    Dictionary<string, object> _parameters;
    public string ProcName
    {
        get { return _procName; }
        set { _procName = value; }
    }


    public Dictionary<string, object> Parameters
    {
        get { return _parameters; }
        set { _parameters = value; }
    }

    public PSCProc(string procName, Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
    {
        _procName = procName;
        _parameters = parameters;
    }
```

and here is the method used to run the stored procedure

```
 public static void execProc(string procName, Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
    {

        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(Test.Properties.Settings.Default.testConnection))
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(procName, conn)
        {
            CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        })
        {
            foreach (var item in parameters)
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue(item.Key, item.Value);
            }
            conn.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
            Form1.updated++;
        }
    }
```

and this is how i add an item to the queue

```
Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            int x = 1;
            string address = "cairo";
            parameters.Add("@id", x);
            parameters.Add("@address", address);
            PSCProc proc1 = new PSCProc("updateAddress", parameters);
            pscQueue.Enqueue(proc1);
```

and this how i run the background worker to run the procedures

```
 PSCProc proc;
            if (pscQueue.TryDequeue(out proc))
            {
                helper.execProc(proc.ProcName, proc.Parameters);
            }
```

Note that:
-the background worker that executes the procedures runs again when it finished.
-the database has too many locks as there are hundreds using it.
-the database is very important to be responsive all the time without any locks.
-connection pooling is saving the connections sleeping or suspended all the time.
-the ratio of adding procedures to the queue won't be faster that the ratio of executing them.

My Question Is

Is it better to use this way or using many connections won't affect the Database.

Comment: Why don't you queue `SqlCommand` objects? - they already have a way of storing a stored procedure name and any required parameters

Answer (score 0):

I would make a SQL Agent job that runs your stored procedure.  Then your connection can login, start the job, and exit, and SQL Agent will run the job in the background.  That way your connections aren't held open while the procedure runs.

That being said, I'll bet your database isn't slow because there are lots of connections, I'll bet it's slow because it's running lots of queries on behalf of those connections.  But without knowing the code of your stored procedure nor your schema it's really impossible to know.

Answer (score 0):

The amount of connections could slowdown the SQL Server depending on the actual amount.

One way of slimming down could be by checking whether or not the application is using connection pooling correctly. See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx) for getting it right. A lot depends on the connection string and the state a connection is left in. (If there are open transactions, different credentials it can't be pooled)

Another way is moving the execution of the procedure(s) to a central service and have that service cache the database requests/responses.

Finally I'd have a look at the procedures/queries themselves; you mention that there is a lot of locking going on. Try and find out why. Did you create an insert hotspot at the end of a table? An index might help removing the hotspot. An (insert) trigger might be in the way. [See this post for more details](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic561850-360-1.aspx#bm562861)